# cannot import openpyxl to python on OSX

Tags: python, openpyxl

I use easy_install to install the openpyxl and it was successfully installed. However when i tried to import it by usin from openpyxml import Workbook command, pycharm did not recognized it. It saus unresolved reference.

Could you help me on this ?

Comment: Please, post the error you get if you want someone to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you've got an extra m in your openpxyl, and you're missing the workbook module.

Try:

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
```